# PHP parse array and count values in new array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a PHP array that looks like this...

```
$array = [

    'item1' => [
        [
            'productCount' => '3',
            'value' => 'red',
        ],
        [
            'productCount' => '3',
            'value' => 'green',
        ],
        [
            'productCount' => '3',
            'value' => 'green',
        ]
    ],

    'item2' => [
        [
            'productCount' => '1',
            'value' => 'purple',
        ]
    ],

];
```

I am trying to parse it so it looks like this...

```
Array
(
    [item1] => Array
        (
            [productCount] => 3
            [red] => 1
            [green] => 2
        )
    [item1] => Array
        (
            [productCount] => 1
            [purple] => 1
        )
)
```

I have this so far....

```
$finalArray = array();

foreach ($array as $key => $arrayItem) {

    $finalArray[$key] = $arrayItem['productCount'];

    $valueCount = count($arrayItem['productCount']);

    $finalArray[$key] = $valueCount;

}
```

I know this isn't much but I am stuck at this point. How do I process the values and count them in the new array?

Comment: You are currently only looping over the first level of your array. You either need to explicitly loop the second level as well, or you use `array_values` to extract only the content under the `value` keys on that level, so that you can then count how many times each value occurs using `array_count_values`

Comment: In you reqquirement I found the index `item1` two time, it is not possible to make that , Same index name will get overwritten

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will give you the results you want. It loops over the upper level array to get the keys and `productCount` values for the new array. Then it loops over the second level arrays to get the counts of each `value`:

```
$output = array();
foreach ($array as $key => $items) {
    $output[$key] = array('productCount' => $items[0]['productCount']);
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $value = $item['value'];
        $output[$key][$value] = ($output[$key][$value] ?? 0) + 1;
    }
}
print_r($output);
```

The inner loop can be written more concisely using [`array_column`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) and [`array_count_values`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php):

```
$output = array();
foreach ($array as $key => $items) {
    $output[$key] = array_merge(array('productCount' => $items[0]['productCount']),
                                array_count_values(array_column($items, 'value')));
}
print_r($output);
```

In both cases the output is:

```
Array
(
    [item1] => Array
        (
            [productCount] => 3
            [red] => 1
            [green] => 2
        )
    [item2] => Array
        (
            [productCount] => 1
            [purple] => 1
        )
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/3KACg)

Answer (score 1):

For dynamic get all result use two times `foreach` loops

```
$array = [
    'item1' => [
        [
            'productCount' => '3',
            'value' => 'red',
        ],
        [
            'productCount' => '3',
            'value' => 'green',
        ],
        [
            'productCount' => '3',
            'value' => 'green',
        ]
    ],
    'item2' => [
        [
            'productCount' => '1',
            'value' => 'purple',
        ]
    ],
];
$new_array = $final_array = array();
foreach ($array as $key => $arrayItem) {
        foreach($arrayItem as $sub_key=>$second_item){
            $new_array[$key]['productCount'] = $second_item['productCount'];             
            $new_array[$key][$second_item['value']][] =$second_item['value'];           
        }
}
foreach ($new_array as $key => $value) {
        foreach($value as $sub_key =>$sub_value){
            $final_array[$key][$sub_key] = (is_array($sub_value))?count($sub_value):$sub_value;
        }
}
print_r($final_array);exit;
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [item1] => Array
        (
            [productCount] => 3
            [red] => 1
            [green] => 2
        )

    [item2] => Array
        (
            [productCount] => 1
            [purple] => 1
        )

)
```

Hope this is helpful to you.